# Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header: for (siteground hosting)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file, and I use super cache plugin and pagespeed from google.

```
# TN - START EXPIRES CACHING #
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
# TN - END EXPIRES CACHING #

# TN - BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# TN - END Cache-Control Headers

# TN - BEGIN Turn ETags Off
FileETag None
# TN - END Turn ETags Off

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN supercache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.html\.gz$">
    ForceType text/html
    FileETag None
  </FilesMatch>
  AddEncoding gzip .gz
  AddType text/html .gz
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.gz$ no-gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding, Cookie"
  Header set Cache-Control 'max-age=3, must-revalidate'
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType text/html A3
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
# END supercache

Options All -Indexes
```

And if I deactivate cdn I get error in speed testing:

> The following publicly cacheable, compressible resources should have a "Vary: Accept-Encoding" header:
>   https://droidawy.com/wp-content,_plugins,_mh-lo ... asonry.js,qver==4.2.1.pagespeed.jc.aJe1qC-NMI.js
>   ttps://droidawy.com/wp-content,_themes,_mharty ... t.min.js,qver==1.11.4.pagespeed.jc.vbNvVnCSV-.js
>   https://droidawy.com/wp-content/plugins/heateor ... ront.css,qver=1.4.12.pagespeed.cf.bcGmYWboif.css
>   https://droidawy.com/wp-content/plugins/host-analyticsjs-local/cache/local-ga.js
>   ttps://droidawy.com/wp-content/plugins/mh-auth ... style.css,qver=1.3.1.pagespeed.cf.sg490QkEIx.css
>   https://droidawy.com/wp-content/plugins/mh-love ... style.css,qver=2.1.1.pagespeed.cf.IEZBYGhsBU.css
>   ttps://droidawy.com/wp-content/plugins/mh-maga ... style.css,qver=2.0.1.pagespeed.cf.k8FUittoKh.css
>   includes/js/jquery/jquery.js,qver=1.12.4.pagespeed.jm.pPCPAKkkss.js
>   https://droidawy.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.9

And I tried this code but it is not solved:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

SiteGround's SuperCacher plugin does not (normally) require any modification to your .htaccess file.

Remove the supercache entries in .htaccess and then re-enable the CDN, clear the CDN cache, and try again.

On a side note, consider using Google Chrome's Audit tab in the Inspector to test your site's speed as many online tools are making assumptions about your hosting that aren't true. In particular, many of the tools are aimed at HTTP/1.1 servers whereas SiteGround offers HTTP/2 (which is a whole different paradigm when it comes to delivering content).

Good luck.

Comment: thank you for valuable informations, but i use pagespeed which deactivate siteground cache, i use wp super cache plugin, so i have to edit .htaccess
when i deactivate my Cloudflare CDN i feel my site speed is better

any other ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure SiteGround has it's own plugin called SuperCacher (or something very similar). Can you check and see if it is available for your account? On dedicated servers it is available via cPanel. Please let me know here.

Comment: ya it there, but when i use pagespeed it deactivated auto, so i use page speed and wp super cache + htaccess leverage browser cache

Comment: Yes, I guess my "answer" isn't really an answer as I'm suggesting you ditch GPS and WP-Super-Cache in exchange for SiteGround's own SuperCacher plugin. SG also offers a Static Cache (just above the GPS option). Good luck.